# Ada extension aggregate initialization

Tags: oop, initialization, ada

Well I'm quite sure this is easy :)

I have an abstract tagged type *NamedStructure* having three fields in the private part of the spec:

- name (a string)
- structure (roughly an array)
- number (an positive)

I then created a subclass *Chord* which is basically:

```ada
type Chord is new NamedStructure with null record;
```

Playing around with Spark, I need to initialize my *chord* objects but I face a problem.

```ada
Chord_Object : Chord := (NamedStructure'(Name => "", 
                                         Structure => (Others => False), 
                                         Number_Of_Notes => 0) with null record);
```

doesn't compile and the error message is

```
scalada-chords.adb:44:53: expected private type "NamedStructure" defined at scalada-namedstructures.ads:52
scalada-chords.adb:44:53: found a composite type
```

I don't find the correct construction using the extension aggregate and I don't see why. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that `NamedStructure` is a private type and therefore cannot be initialized using an aggregate. You might try

```
type Chord is new NamedStructure with null record;

Chord_Object : Chord := (NamedStructure with null record);
```

although the instance fields of `NamedStructure` will now remain uninitialized.

Comment: Yes, _NamedStructure_ is a private type but as it is the superclass of _Chord_ I was expecting its components to be visible but I am certainly wrong. I'll have to read my Barnes once again :)

Comment: As an add-on, as you mention SPARK in your question, the type extension might, in this case, also not be allowed in SPARK (see also [SPARK RM 3.9.1 (1) )](http://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/lrm/declarations-and-types.html#type-extensions).

Comment: Yes, you're right about Spark ! I changed the way I build my objects and I found a mistake. I made a constructor with _in out_ signature instead of _out_ only which forced me to initialize the object.